# Is there an affordable laptop/netbook, with GPS?

Tags: laptop, netbook, gps

I'm looking to buy a new netbook, or laptop. I'm not looking for a monster capable of running games, and I'd like one able to use the GPS system.

Some models with GPS seem a bit pricey, and the pcmcia cards look enormous. I even read the instructions of the guy who put a gps unit in is eeePC, but it seems a bit too complicated to do for me, plus he says he gets a bad reception.

If we can have gps in a iphone, surely it mustn't be that hard to have it in a netbook ?

Comment: could you please turn 'affordable' into some .. numeric value + currency?

Comment: About 400 euros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASUS' **[Eee PC T91](http://www.asus.com/Eee/Eee_PC/Eee_PC_T91/)** is equipped with a TV tuner and Global Positioning System (GPS).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The [Dell Mini 10](http://www.dell.com/us/en/home/notebooks/laptop-inspiron-10/pd.aspx?refid=laptop-inspiron-10&cs=19&s=dhs) (pictured), and the [Eee PC T91](http://www.asus.com/Eee/Eee_PC/Eee_PC_T91/) have a built in GPS and are both in your price range.  Also, you can buy a GPS receiver and software for a laptop or netbook.

Answer (score 1):

I used a regular laptop with this thing [GPS-18](http://images.google.com/images?hl=en&safe=off&sa=1&q=garmin+gps+18+receiver+usb&aq=f&oq=&aqi=&start=0) - worked fine. Could save some money if you've already got a laptop/netbook, and the thing is practically indestructible (fell off the car's roof), and has an excellent signal receiver.